# I want to implement the predicate noDupl/2 in Prolog & have trouble with singleton variables

Tags: list, prolog

My confusion mainly lies around understanding singleton variables.

I want to implement the predicate `noDupl/2` in Prolog. This predicate can be used to identify numbers in a list that appear exactly once, i. e., numbers which are no duplicates. The first argument of `noDupl` is the list to analyze. The
second argument is the list of numbers which are no duplicates, as described below.
As an example, for the list `[2, 0, 3, 2, 1]` the result `[0, 3, 1]` is computed (because `2` is a duplicate).
In my implementation I used the predefined member predicate and used an auxiliary predicate called helper.

I'll explain my logic in pseudocode, so you can help me spot where I went wrong.

1. First off, If the first element is not a member of the rest of the list, add the first element to the new result List (as it's head).
2. If the first element is a member of `T`, call the helper method on the rest of the list, the first element `H` and the new list.
3. Helper method, if `H` is found in the tail, return list without `H`, i. e., `Tail`.

   ```
   noDupl([],[]).
   noDupl([H|T],L) :-
      \+ member(H,T),
       noDupl(T,[H|T]).
   noDupl([H|T],L) :-
      member(H,T),
      helper(T,H,L).

   helper([],N,[]).
   helper([H|T],H,T). %found place of duplicate & return list without it
   helper([H|T],N,L) :-
      helper(T,N,[H|T1]).%still couldn't locate the place, so add H to the new List as it's not a duplicate
   ```

While I'm writing my code, I'm always having trouble with deciding to choose a new variable or use the one defined in the predicate arguments when it comes to free variables specifically.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect for `noDupl([a,a,a], Xs)`?

Answer (score 5):

**Warnings about singleton variables are not the actual problem.**

Singleton variables are logical variables that occur once in some Prolog clause (fact or rule). Prolog warns you about these variables if they are named like non-singleton variables, i. e., if their name does not start with a `_`.

This convention helps avoid typos of the nasty kind—typos which do not cause syntax errors but *do* change the meaning.

---

**Let's build a canonical solution to your problem.**

First, forget about `CamelCase` and pick a proper predicate name that reflects the relational nature of the problem at hand: how about `list_uniques/2`?

Then, document cases in which you expect the predicate to give one answer, multiple answers or no answer at all. How?
Not as mere text, but as *queries*.

Start with the most general query:

```
?- list_uniques(Xs, Ys).
```

Add some ground queries:

```
?- list_uniques([], []).
?- list_uniques([1,2,2,1,3,4], [3,4]).
?- list_uniques([a,b,b,a], []).
```

And add queries containing variables:

```
?- list_uniques([n,i,x,o,n], Xs).
?- list_uniques([i,s,p,y,i,s,p,y], Xs).

?- list_uniques([A,B], [X,Y]).
?- list_uniques([A,B,C], [D,E]).
?- list_uniques([A,B,C,D], [X]).
```

Now let's write some code! Based on [`library(reif)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/) write:

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).

list_uniques(Xs, Ys) :-
   list_past_uniques(Xs, [], Ys).

list_past_uniques([], _, []).           % auxiliary predicate
list_past_uniques([X|Xs], Xs0, Ys) :-
   if_((memberd_t(X,Xs) ; memberd_t(X,Xs0)),
       Ys = Ys0,
       Ys = [X|Ys0]),
   list_past_uniques(Xs, [X|Xs0], Ys0).
```

What's going on?

- `list_uniques/2` is built upon the helper predicate `list_past_uniques/3`
- At any point, `list_past_uniques/3` keeps track of:

  - all items ahead (`Xs`) *and*
  - all items "behind" (`Xs0`) some item of the original list `X`.
- If `X` is a member of *either* list, then `Ys` skips `X`—it's *not unique*!
- Otherwise, `X` *is* unique and it occurs in `Ys` (as its list head).

Let's run some of the above queries using SWI-Prolog 8.0.0:

```
?- list_uniques(Xs, Ys).
   Xs = [], Ys = []
;  Xs = [_A], Ys = [_A]
;  Xs = [_A,_A], Ys = []
;  Xs = [_A,_A,_A], Ys = []
...

?- list_uniques([], []).
true.
?- list_uniques([1,2,2,1,3,4], [3,4]).
true.
?- list_uniques([a,b,b,a], []).
true.

?- list_uniques([1,2,2,1,3,4], Xs).
Xs = [3,4].
?- list_uniques([n,i,x,o,n], Xs).
Xs = [i,x,o].
?- list_uniques([i,s,p,y,i,s,p,y], Xs).
Xs = [].

?- list_uniques([A,B], [X,Y]).
A = X, B = Y, dif(Y,X).
?- list_uniques([A,B,C], [D,E]).
false.
?- list_uniques([A,B,C,D], [X]).
   A = B, B = C, D = X, dif(X,C)
;  A = B, B = D, C = X, dif(X,D)
;  A = C, C = D, B = X, dif(D,X)
;  A = X, B = C, C = D, dif(D,X)
;  false.
```

Comment: I know I am the only one currently doing test cases for Prolog tag, but what is your view on posting test cases with answers?

Comment: @GuyCoder. Thank you! Every query *is* a test case. I'm actually not quite sure about the best way to do it. Brevity is important, too. Also, I'm not sure if the particular format is a bit different on different StackExchange sites. Maybe a SO-answer in combination with a CodeReview-answer could help. OTOH Prolog is lo-freq on CR.

Comment: Does 8.0.0 really write `_A`? That would be fabulous. At least, 8.0.1 doesn't.

Comment: @false. No, SWI-Prolog 8.0.0 does not produce decent output for anonymous variables. One fine day it might, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @false. Thx for the better name!

Comment: A better toplevel could showcase `variable_names/1`

Answer (score 3):

Just like [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55048527/4609915), the following answer is based on `library(reif)`—and uses it in a somewhat more idiomatic way.

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).

list_uniques([], []).
list_uniques([V|Vs], Xs) :-
   tpartition(=(V), Vs, Equals, Difs),
   if_(Equals = [], Xs = [V|Xs0], Xs = Xs0),
   list_uniques(Difs, Xs0).
```

While this code does *not* improve upon my previous one regarding efficiency / complexity, it is arguably more readable (fewer arguments in the recursion).

Comment: Consider `length(Vs,N), maplist(=(_),Vs), list_uniques(Vs, Us)` which now is linear. It used to be, er, something quadratic. In the general case, your improvement is of similar complexity, indeed.  I think we really need some refinements. After all, `Equals` is a waste, a single truth value would suffice.

Comment: Correction: My testcase was not a perfect one.

Comment: @false. Enforcing a relationship between the lengths of `Vs` and `Us` might be helpful in some cases.

Comment: The case I gave still exposes cases of waste in the original program - the reconstruction of the list. So this answer is (sometimes) an improvement

Answer (score 3):

In this solution a slightly modified version of `tpartition` is used to have more control over what happens when an item passes the condition (or not):

```
tpartition_p(P_2, OnTrue_5, OnFalse_5, OnEnd_4, InitialTrue, InitialFalse, Xs, RTrue, RFalse) :-
   i_tpartition_p(Xs, P_2, OnTrue_5, OnFalse_5, OnEnd_4, InitialTrue, InitialFalse, RTrue, RFalse).

i_tpartition_p([], _P_2, _OnTrue_5, _OnFalse_5, OnEnd_4, CurrentTrue, CurrentFalse, RTrue, RFalse):-
  call(OnEnd_4, CurrentTrue, CurrentFalse, RTrue, RFalse).
i_tpartition_p([X|Xs], P_2, OnTrue_5, OnFalse_5, OnEnd_4, CurrentTrue, CurrentFalse, RTrue, RFalse):-
   if_( call(P_2, X)
      , call(OnTrue_5, X, CurrentTrue, CurrentFalse, NCurrentTrue, NCurrentFalse)
      , call(OnFalse_5, X, CurrentTrue, CurrentFalse, NCurrentTrue, NCurrentFalse) ),
   i_tpartition_p(Xs, P_2, OnTrue_5, OnFalse_5, OnEnd_4, NCurrentTrue, NCurrentFalse, RTrue, RFalse).
```

`InitialTrue`/`InitialFalse` and `RTrue`/`RFalse` contains the desired initial and final state, procedures `OnTrue_5` and `OnFalse_5` manage state transition after testing the condition `P_2` on each item and `OnEnd_4` manages the last transition.

With the following code for `list_uniques/2`:

```
list_uniques([], []).
list_uniques([V|Vs], Xs) :-
   tpartition_p(=(V), on_true, on_false, on_end, false, Difs, Vs, HasDuplicates, []),
   if_(=(HasDuplicates), Xs=Xs0, Xs = [V|Xs0]),
   list_uniques(Difs, Xs0).


on_true(_, _, Difs, true, Difs).

on_false(X, HasDuplicates, [X|Xs], HasDuplicates, Xs).

on_end(HasDuplicates, Difs, HasDuplicates, Difs).
```

When the item passes the filter (its a duplicate) we just mark that the list has duplicates and skip the item, otherwise the item is kept for further processing.

Comment: In place of `if_(HasDuplicates = true, ...` you can write `if_(=(HasDuplicates), ...` which is a bit safer as non-boolean values issue a type error and variables an instantiation error.

Comment: Very original solution! Still unclear why you use `Current` so frequently. Aren't difference-numbers appropriate?

Comment: @false: you are right about using `=(HasDuplicates)`, changed it. Regarding using `Current` frequently, I'm not sure what you meant by using _difference-numbers_ instead. Do you have an example of link to clarify your suggestion ?

Comment: Like the numbering for difference lists. Think of `a(X0,X) :- b(X0,X1),c(X1,X2),d(X2,X).`

Answer (score 2):

This answer goes similar ways as [this previous answer by @gusbro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55230471/4609915).

However, it does not propose a somewhat [baroque](http://www.hacker-dictionary.com/terms/baroque) version of `tpartition/4`, but instead an augmented, but hopefully leaner, version of `tfilter/3` called `tfilter_t/4` which can be defined like so:

```
tfilter_t(C_2, Es, Fs, T) :-
   i_tfilter_t(Es, C_2, Fs, T).

i_tfilter_t([], _, [], true).
i_tfilter_t([E|Es], C_2, Fs0, T) :-
   if_(call(C_2,E), 
       ( Fs0 = [E|Fs], i_tfilter_t(Es,C_2,Fs,T) ),
       ( Fs0 = Fs, T = false, tfilter(C_2,Es,Fs) )).
```

Adapting `list_uniques/2` is straightforward:

```
list_uniques([], []).
list_uniques([V|Vs], Xs) :-
   if_(tfilter_t(dif(V),Vs,Difs), Xs = [V|Xs0], Xs = Xs0),
   list_uniques(Difs, Xs0).
```

Save scrollbars. Stay lean! Use `filter_t/4`.

Comment: `tfilter_t/4` or similar. Something ending with `_t`

Comment: @false. At first I didn't see it... Better now.

Answer (score -1):

You have problems already in the first predicate, `noDupl/2`.

The first clause, `noDupl([], []).` looks fine.
The second clause is wrong.

```
noDupl([H|T],L):-
    \+member(H,T),
    noDupl(T,[H|T]).
```

What does that really mean I leave as an exercise to you. If you want, however, to add `H` to the result, you would write it like this:

```
noDupl([H|T], [H|L]) :-
    \+ member(H, T),
    noDupl(T, L).
```

Please look carefully at this and try to understand. The `H` is added to the result by unifying the result (the second argument in the head) to a list with `H` as the head and the variable `L` as the tail. The singleton variable `L` in your definition is a singleton because there is a mistake in your definition, namely, you do nothing at all with it.

The last clause has a different kind of problem. You try to clean the rest of the list from this one element, but you never return to the original task of getting rid of all duplicates. It could be fixed like this:

```
noDupl([H|T], L) :-
    member(H, T),
    helper(T, H, T0),
    noDupl(T0, L).
```

Your `helper/3` cleans the rest of the original list from the duplicate, unifying the result with `T0`, then uses this clean list to continue removing duplicates.

Now on to your helper. The first clause seems fine but has a singleton variable. This is a valid case where you don't want to do anything with this argument, so you "declare" it unused for example like this:

```
helper([], _, []).
```

The second clause is problematic because it removes a single occurrence. What should happen if you call:

```
?- helper([1,2,3,2], 2, L).
```

The last clause also has a problem. Just because you use different names for two variables, this doesn't make them different. To fix these two clauses, you can for example do:

```
helper([H|T], H, L) :-
    helper(T, H, L).
helper([H|T], X, [H|L]) :-
    dif(H, X),
    helper(T, X, L).
```

These are the minimal corrections that will give you an answer when the first argument of `noDupl/2` is ground. You could do this check this by renaming `noDupl/2` to `noDupl_ground/2` and defining `noDupl/2` as:

```
noDupl(L, R) :-
    must_be(ground, L),
    noDupl_ground(L, R).
```

Try to see what you get for different queries with the current naive implementation and ask if you have further questions. It is still full of problems, but it really depends on how you will use it and what you want out of the answer.

Comment: @false Many things fail or do not terminate. There should probably be a `must_be(ground)` for the first argument of `noDupl/2` with this implementation.

Comment: @false I must be very confused. `?- noDupl([a,a], []).` should succeed once (which it does). Is `X = a, noDupl([a, X], []).` a different query?

Comment: `noDupl([a,X],[a,b]).` fails, yet `X = b, noDupl([a,X],[a,b]).` succeeds. So the more specialized query succeeds.

Comment: And, after your groundness check: `noDupl([a,a,a],[]).` succeeds three times.

Comment: @false Yes. As I said in my answer, this is full of problems. But the question doesn't really invite to go too deep in any particular direction, short of "this is how you should be doing it instead".

Comment: Shouldn't we give better answers?